# Not allowing me to pass false value while using child to parent component interaction

Tags: angular, angular-material, components, angular-components

Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.ts(2345)

```
cancel() {
this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are trying to pass a `boolean` value to an `EventEmitter` that is expecting a `string` or `symbol`.

Make sure that `cancelRegister` is defined like:

```
cancelRegister = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

OR leave it as is and pass a string value to `emit`